# To construct examples of bounded linear functional.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $L$ be a linear functional on $H$.

Then $L$ is said to be a bounded linear functional iff
$\exists c>0:\forall h\in H:|Lh|\leq c\|h\|.$
 I want to construct some non trivial example of a bounded linear functional from Hilbert Space $H$ to Hilbert Space $K$. Also an example of the same taking $H=K$. 
Thanks .

Comment: The term 'functional' is reserved for linear maps where your $K$ is the field of scalars. If $H=K$ then the functionals are $f(x)=ax$ for some $a\in K$.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way. Take a vector $v$ and define the functional $\langle v,\cdot\rangle:H \to \mathbb K$, given by $\langle v, \cdot \rangle(w):=\langle v, w \rangle$.

These are in fact all of the bounded linear functionals. This is the [Riesz representation theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

Take an arbitrary $h\in H$ and an arbitrary $k \in K$ and let $(.,.)_{H}$ denote the scalar product in $H$. Then you can define
$$
L:\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
H&\to &K \\
x &\mapsto & (x,h)_H \cdot k
\end{array}
\right.
$$
which is linear because the scalar product is linear in the first component and bounded because
$$
\|(x,h)_H \cdot k \| = |(x,h)_H|\cdot \|k\| \leq \|x\|\cdot\|h\|\cdot\|k\|.
$$